# Can Javascript be replaced with another language?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, client-side-scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930716/alternatives-to-javascript)

Hi there,

As there are many programming languages, and you have options, that which ever language you want to work on, like you if you use C# then you have option that you can use VB.NET or C++ etc further you we have Java which can replace C# or C# that can replace Java. So we have options.

My question is that as Javascript is used in client side scripting so is there any language which can replace Javascript?

Is there any language which we can use for the purposes for which we use java Script.

Your opinions and replies will be Highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to Javascript as used exlusively by web browsers:

- Not directly, since the browsers all
  support javascript exclusively. But
  there are javascript
  libraries/frameworks you can use that
  allow you to build client-side
  applications in other languages.

  For
  example:
  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_web_browser

  Another option would simply be to use an x->javascript compiler where x is your language of choice.

If you are referring to Javascript as used everywhere else:

- You can **very** easily use other languages for such tasks. Simply pick a language that you like, and use it instead!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of places that JavaScript is used that have nothing to do with client side scripting, but to answer the question I think you are asking:

There is no programming language that can run client side in browsers, which has access to the DOM, and has anywhere near the support that JavaScript has.

If you limit yourself to Internet Explorer, then VBScript might be an option. This is hostile to the web, and imposes restrictions on software choice within a company in an Intranet environment.

If you don't need access to the DOM, or want to interface with JavaScript for just DOM manipulation, then ActionScript (via Flash) and .NET languages (via Silverlight) become an option. Support for these is not as wide as vanilla JavaScript though.

If you are willing to dump through a layer of abstraction (with the complications and limitations that implies) then tools such as GWT will let you write in one language and translate it to JavaScript in a "compilation" step.