# What's the front-end DOM manipulation alternatives besides JS?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, frontend

Say I am tired of JS, what's the front-end DOM manipulation alternatives besides JS? And it can give the user interaction power the same what JS can give.

Comment: There are some other languages that compile to JS (which it needs to end up with as that is the only scripting language the browser accepts without plugins).

Comment: You will always need JS. If you are tired of vanilla you can jump into jquery or most recently react to achieve more in less time and have some syntax sugar.

Comment: Right, it all ends up being javascript. You can look into Elm, CoffeeScript, TypeScript. Here's a full list https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930716/alternatives-to-javascript)